# Javascirpt dynamic html with checkbox checked

Tags: javascript

I have below code to generate html with checkbox

```js
var check = true;

var html = `<input ` + check ? 'checked' : ' ' + ` type="checkbox" value="text" />`;
console.log(html)
document.getElementById("dv").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="dv"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yn8q0sdv/

But this is not working

Thanks

Comment: As a side note - if you're using template literals, you don't need to do string concatenation.

Comment: There is a typo, <div id="dv"></div> vs <div id="div"></div>, this might be the reason for you not getting the element :)

Comment: @CheshireKatzzze no, it's not.

Comment: you have to wrap your condition in (). So do it like this: var html = `<input ` + (check ? 'checked' : ' ') + ` type="checkbox" value="text" />`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how your value logged to console says `checked` *only*?

That’s due to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

You need to put braces around the ternary operator part of the expression here, then it will work:

```
var html = `<input ` + (check ? 'checked' : ' ') + ` type="checkbox" value="text" />`;
```

Comment: Do not use '+' sign instead use template literals provided way:

`<input ${check ? `checked` : ``} type="checkbox" value="text" />`

Answer (score 3):

```
var check = true;

var checked = check ? 'checked' : ' ';

var html = '<input ' + checked + ' type="checkbox" value="text" />';
console.log(html)
document.getElementById("dv").innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var checkbox = document.createElement('input');

checkbox.type = "checkbox";

document.getElementById("dv").appendChild(checkbox)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need with template literals:

```
var check = true;

var html = `<input ${check ? `checked` : ``} type="checkbox" value="text" />`;
console.log(html)
document.getElementById("dv").innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using a ternary operator inside string concatenation in a way that *changes the semantics*. When you do `"start " + bool ? "a" : "b" + " end"` this would be interpreted as `("start " + bool) ? "a" : ("b" + " end")`, so you *either* get `"a"` or `"b" + " end"`. The initial expression will always be truthy (string concatenation between a non-empty string and anything else), so you always get the true branch of the ternary.

```js
var bool = true;

var result = "start " + bool ? "a" : "b" + " end";

console.log(result);

bool = false;
result = "start " + bool ? "a" : "b" + " end";

console.log(result);
```

If you *do* use string concatenation and a ternary, you need to group the ternary:

```js
var bool = true;

var result = "start " + (bool ? "a" : "b") + " end";

console.log(result);

bool = false;
result = "start " + (bool ? "a" : "b") + " end";

console.log(result);
```

However, since you're using a template literal, you can just evaluate the expression directly

```js
var check = true;

var html = `<input ${check ? 'checked' : ' '} type="checkbox" value="text" />`;
console.log(html)
document.getElementById("dv").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="dv"></div>
```

An even better idea is to not generate HTML but create the element programmatically:

```js
var check = true;

var element = document.createElement("input");

element.type = "checkbox";
element.value = "text";
element.checked = check;

console.log(element)
document.getElementById("dv").appendChild(element);
```

```html
<div id="dv"></div>
```